# Access a list data member in a class

Tags: c#, class

I have a class defined like:

```
public class Paths //class point definition
    {
        public List<Point> points;
        public Color color;
        public Paths(List<Point> POINTS, Color COLOR)
        {
            points = POINTS;
            color = COLOR;
        }
    }
```

in my source code I make a list: `List<Paths> PATHS = new List<Paths>();`

then I make a list of points: `List<Point> newPath = null;` then I add some stuff to it: `newPath.Add(x, y);`

now I want this newPath to be inserted in my PATHS list along with a color. How do I do this?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? The way you do the addressing seems fine to me.

Comment: I also make a list of Paths objects but I get errors!

Comment: color and point are public properties of the class. So every instance of the Paths class has its own sets of points and its color. And because they are public the syntax used in your question is absolutely legal. Intellisense should show you the two properties.

Comment: If you have errors then you should show also the code that raises the errors

Comment: ok I'll edit my question

Comment: @Steve I edited my question

Comment: "I also make a list of Paths objects but I get errors!" You show neither how you create a list of paths (or the individual paths themselves) nor the actual error you get. Good questions will include enough detail necessary to diagnose the problem.  In this case the error you get would very likely have made the problem apparent,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then I make a list of points: `List<Point> newPath = null;`

No, you created a *variable* that could reference a list - you need to actually create the list:

```
List<Point> newPath = new List<Point>();
```

*then* you can add `Point` object to it.

> now I want this `newPath` to be inserted in my PATHS list along with a color. How do I do this?

You need to create a `Path` as well:

```
Path path = new Path();

path.points = newPath;
```

Note the following suggestions to get closer to C# conventions:

- Use properties instead of fields for public members
- Start public property names with a capital letter (e.g. `Points`)
- start parameter names with a lower-case letter (e.g. `public Paths(List<Point> points, Color color)`

Comment: I'm going to create a list of class objects like this: `List<Paths> PATHS = new List<Paths>()`